# how to split traffic from same url path to 2 different upstreams?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-upstreams

i have these upstreams declared:

```
upstream upstream_1 {
    server some_container_1:8000;
}

upstream upstream_2 {
    server some_container_2:8001;
}
```

and this server:

```
server {
    listen       7000;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /path {
        uwsgi_pass  upstream_1;
    }
}
```

where both `some_container_1` and `some_container_2` are based on same image (thus offer the same apis on the same paths) but differ on env vars and other non related stuff. i want to fork 1% of all traffic from `localhost:7000/path` to be delivered 'as is' to `upstream_2` and 99% to remain on `upstream_1`. both cases should keep the request as received, altering neither path nor headers

with [split_clients](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html) i can fork which path will be set before forwarding the request to a single upstream, which is not my case.

[here](https://www.viget.com/articles/split-test-traffic-distribution-with-nginx/) the fork is done inside an upstream between servers, not inside a location splitting between upstreams, as i need.

can i define an upstream of upstreams like

```
upstream compound_upstream_1 {
    upstream upstream_1 weight=99;
    upstream upstream_2;
}
```

to use it on

```
server {
    listen       7000;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /path {
        uwsgi_pass  compound_upstream_1;
    }
```

is it possible to do this with nginx? considering so, which way should be the standard to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand, what stops you from using server names in the upstream block directly?

```
upstream compound_upstream_1 {
    server some_container_1:8000 weight=99;
    server some_container_2:8001;
}
server {
    listen       7000;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /path {
        uwsgi_pass  compound_upstream_1;
    }
}
```

Or maybe I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to accomplish this using a load balancer: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/

I'm not sure what the weights would be for your '1%' scenario but you can toy with it and adjust it to your liking.